# when you login to the shell, what program handles evaluation of the credentials?

Tags: command-line, bash, login, source-code

when you first boot, and you're greeted with the warm glow of a black screen and flashing prompt, what program is that? What program handles evaluation of the credentials? Or rather, what component of the source code is it? I may be confusing myself, but I think the various user shells are loaded after user authentication.

... which might mean that bash is launched in single user mode, then bash checks credentials & launches a user shell? (I think this is how it works)

(Im interested in adding a feature to the credential checking process, but I'm looking at bash source code, and I'm not sure where to begin. )

Comment: I don't think a shell is involved until *after* authentication; `getty` invokes `login`, which probably then uses the `pam_unix` module for basic password authentication. If you want to add an authentication feature you will probably be looking at writing a custom PAM module.

Comment: ... here's a possible template [Externally authenticate user within PAM session/PAM session within PAM session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162556/externally-authenticate-user-within-pam-session-pam-session-within-pam-session)

Comment: now that I'm looking at it a bit more, maybe I can inspect the boot process a little more to find out exactly whats happening.  I think maybe `/bin/login` is what I should be looking at.  `type -a login` shows login isn't a shell built in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I have only a rudimentary understanding myself, however I'll post this to get you started:*

First, you don't log in to a shell, you log in to a (virtual) terminal.

- a `getty` program opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes a login program (`/bin/login` by default - although Linux's `agetty` may be configured to use a non-standard login program)
- the login program performs authentication and session setup, including initializing the environment and invoking the user's login shell.

In current Ubuntu systems, `getty` is managed as a systemd service (ex. `getty@tty1.service` for the virtual terminal tty1), and `login` uses the Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) subsystem for authentication - in particular, the `pam_unix` module is "for traditional password authentication".

For your stated goal (*"adding a feature to the credential checking process"*) you would probably want to look at implementing a custom PAM module, and inserting it into an appropriate place in the PAM stack; a template for that is described here:

- [Externally authenticate user within PAM session/PAM session within PAM session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162556/externally-authenticate-user-within-pam-session-pam-session-within-pam-session)

See also:

- [10.1. Logins via terminals](https://linux.die.net/sag/login-via-terminal.html) from the Linux System Administrators Guide: Chapter 10. Logging In And Out
- The [archwiki getty page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty)

Comment: I think this is a good start, much appreciated.

Comment: Just small details to add: `getty` normally prompts the user for username and reads it. The `login` program is then invoked using `exec()` call replacing the `getty` process. The username retrieved by `getty` is given to `login` as a parameter. --- After certain number of failed login attempts the program `login` exits and the `getty` process is automatically started anew by the system service manager (`systemd` or `init` in older systems). The same automatic restart happens when the session is ended. --- https://linux.die.net/sag/login-via-terminal.html

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong thanks - I have added your reference and clarified the role of getty